# [electrical cad drawing][pywinauto] want to locate elements in drawing area

Tags: pytorch, tesseract, python-tesseract, pywinauto, easyocr

[image: Drawing area]

Working on a electrical software automation. Would like to right click on some elements or add elements, draw wire between elements. But using pywinauto cant access this area, as it shows as pane. This "Pane" dosent have children/descendants. Can we use image processing like opencv or pytorch to get the lables of the elements and their respective coordinates on the drawing area and then do actions like click, drag etc? I am new to open cv or pytouch, please help

One idea is to get the text coordinates, for this tried, easyocr and pytesseract.

any ideas or solutions will help